# What does it modify? The noun "heat" or the whole phrase "the value of heat"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases

I'd like to learn what the part "*for the preservation of food*" modifies in the following sentence, the noun "*heat*" or the whole phrase "*the value of heat*" .

- The value of heat for the preservation of food has been known for a long time.

What do you think?

I think "*for the preservation of food*" refers to the whole phrase "*the value of heat*".

"*What value of heat?*"
"*The value of heat for the preservation of food*".

Do you agree with me on it?
Thank you

Comment: Where did you find the sentence?

Comment: In a private English course. But why?

Comment: Not very sure but of the top of my head it does look like it's a part of Verb Phrase. I mean *for the preservation of food*. Something is known for something else. Example: *Mr A is known for his role in tutoring the kids.* Or *He was known for tutoring the kids.*

Comment: You are mistaken. ***for the preservation of food*** is a (syntactically optional) "adjective of purpose" element modifying the specific noun ***heat***. I don't know why you would think that adjectival phrase could apply to the entire noun phrase ***the value of heat*** (which is a credible noun to serve as the "object" of ***knowing** [something]*, but ***the value of something*** can't meaningfully be modified by an adjective telling us what that specific "value" is actually ***for***).

Comment: After here, I asked the same question on another platform. If I am mistaken, why does an English literature and grammar expert agree with me? Have you ever beared in mind the possibility that you are mistaken? https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-part-for-the-preservation-of-food-modify-The-noun-heat-or-the-whole-phrase-the-value-of-heat-The-value-of-heat-for-the-preservation-of-food-has-been-known-for-a-long-time-I-think-it-refers-to-the-whole/answer/Robert-Edward-Lewis

Comment: Jewel, in that link I didn't find any answer yet. It is his own thinking. Well I too agree with @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous.

> The value of heat for the preservation of food has been known for a long time.

One reading is that the kind of heat we are talking about is food-preservation heat. Then *[heat for the preservation of food]* is a phrase.

Imagine this expanded into a dialogue:

- The value of heat has been known for a long time.
- What kind of heat?
- Heat for the preservation of food.

The other reading is that we are talking about what heat-in-general is valuable for: *the value [of heat] [for the preservation of food]*. Expanded as follows:

- The value of heat has been known for a long time.
- Its value for what?
- Its value for the preservation of food.

Without any context I would guess the second reading is more likely.

Answer (score 0):

The 'value' being spoken of here is not just the value of 'heat', but specifically its use for the preservation of food.

If you asked simply "what is the value of heat?", it could refer to the *cost* of generating heat, ie the price of fossil fuels. In your example, it is not talking about monetary value at all. A secondary meaning of 'value' is "*the importance or worth of something for someone*". So, heat is *important* in the process of food preservation.

Answer (score 0):

> Penicillin's value for the treatment of infection ...

Can be restated:

> The value of penicillin for the treatment of infection...

The noun **value** is modified by the prepositional phrase, *for the treatment of infection*, identifying the context for the value. It is not value "as a long term investment", say, or "for stopping squeaks in machinery" or any other kind of value.

The periphrastic genitive and genitive construction (of penicillin, penicillin's) indicate the thing that possesses the value, *penicillin*.

Compare:

> Tom's trick for making light and fluffy scrambled eggs is to beat air bubbles into the eggs and to cook them quickly over fairly high heat.